# How to create an Excel file using a stored procedure

Tags: sql-server, excel, stored-procedures

I have a Blazor application and a SQL Server database. In the application I want to hit a button and I want an excel file to be generated and downloaded to the clients computer with all of the data from a table lets call 'Users'. Other threads seems to use programs I am not (like SSIS/Export Wizard) or assume I am very knowledgeable when this is my first time doing this ever. The best thread I found was this: https://www.sqlteam.com/forums/topic.asp?TOPIC_ID=49926

```sql
create procedure spUsers_generate_excel_with_columns
(
    @db_name    varchar(100),
    @table_name varchar(100),   
    @file_name  varchar(100)
)
as

--Generate column names as a recordset
declare @columns varchar(20), @sql varchar(8000), @data_file varchar(100)

select 
    @columns = coalesce(@columns + ',', '') + column_name+' as ' + column_name 
from 
    information_schema.columns
where 
    table_name = @table_name

select @columns = '''''' + replace(replace(@columns, ' as ', ''''' as '), ',', ',''''')

--Create a dummy file to have actual data
select @data_file = substring(@file_name, 1, len(@file_name) - charindex('\', reverse(@file_name))) + '\data_file.xls'

--Generate column names in the passed EXCEL file
set @sql='exec master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp " select * from (select '+@columns+') as t" queryout "'+@file_name+'" -c'''
exec(@sql)

--Generate data in the dummy file
set @sql='exec master..xp_cmdshell ''bcp "select * from '+@db_name+'..'+@table_name+'" queryout "'+@data_file+'" -c'''
exec(@sql)

--Copy dummy file to passed EXCEL file
set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''type '+@data_file+' >> "'+@file_name+'"'''
exec(@sql)

--Delete dummy file 
set @sql= 'exec master..xp_cmdshell ''del '+@data_file+''''
exec(@sql)
```

But nothing is explained so I don't know what I need to be substituting in.
Like what does `@columns=coalesce(@columns+',','')+column_name+' as '+column_name`  mean.

I've used SQL before and I know inner joins and variables but this seems foreign. I just want everything to be executed in this procedure.

Any help would be appreciated.

Update: It's seems like the best advice is to create a CSV file. And this could be downloaded to clients computer?

Comment: Don't do this in T-SQL. Use an appropriate tool to do this.

Comment: It seems excel file should be CSV file?

Comment: I would create a .csv file, much easier and by default it opens in Excel.

Comment: Why not use Excel's Data, Get Data button to pull in the data from that stored proc? Save the file and then all that needs to be done is open the file and click Refresh

Comment: Though the above code produces files with an `.xls` extension they certainly aren't the legacy BIFF formatted files (yes, I know, that's like "ATM machine") that Excel would expect to find. The only supported way to create Excel files from directly SQL Server is to do so by way of SQL Server Reporting Services and, unless you're using a really old version of SQL Server and SSRS, those will be the modern .xlsx files. But, bonus, you can create report subscriptions so those Excel files can be generated and emailed to somebody on a regular basis.